# iPhone: Move a UIButton without Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, move

There are boatloads of hits on animating a UIButton move. I want to do the opposite - move the button without animation. Is it possible to move a button created in interface builder without animations? If so, would someone mind sharing the method as there is no `setPosition` message.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting different frame? you can move the button by setting different frame to it.

Answer (score 7):

You will need an outlet for the button and you can use either `frame`, `center` or `transform` to move the button.

```
button.frame = newFrame; // where `newFrame` is the frame to move to.
button.center = newCenter; // where `newCenter` is a CGPoint 
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( xDisplacement, yDisplacement);
```

Here `transform` doesn't change the center or the frame but only moves the button.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I liked your answer better, but gave Rahul the credits since he was the first to respond. Please don't take offense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try to use setFrame: `[button setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight)];`